# How would I go about running two python scripts at the same time in a cloud env?

Tags: python, flask, server, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have a python server in a file that needs to get a var from another python file. Problem is, I need both of them to be running at the same time in a cloud environment. I need to start the second one so it can some data via an API, then store it in a var. The server then needs to be up so it can start, grab the data and pass it to the front end. I think my syntax is ok, but can I do this? I tried running both locally and got nothing. Will I be able to do this on the cloud?

sample code

file b

```
import requests

response = ''
def get_data():
        global q
        url = 'apiURL'
        headers = {}
        response = requests.request('GET', url, data='payload', headers=headers)
        q.put(response)
```

file a

```
from threading import Thread
import helper
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def start_helper():
        thread_process = Thread(target=helper.get_data)
        thread_process.start()

def get_results():
        global q
        result = q.get()
        return result

start_helper()
print("helper started")
result = get_results()
print("got results")
print(result)
print("ok")
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is threads, I assume. Threads enable parallel processing/execution. Assume you have two python files, `a.py` and `b.py`, and a third one containing your global variables, named `globals.py`.

`a.py` needs to fetch data from an api call made inside `b.py`. You can achieve this by declaring the function that makes the api call in `b.py`, and running it in a thread within `a.py`

This is you sample `globals.py` file:

```
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
```

This is your sample code in `b.py` file:

```
from globals import q

#lots of Python stuff

#function to be called in thread
def my_api_call():
    #some api call made and result stored in a variable named 'result'
    global q
    q.put(result)

#lots of other Python stuff
```

This is your sample code in `a.py` file:

```
from threading import Thread
from globals import q
import b


def start_api_call_in_b():
        thread_process = Thread(target=b.my_api_call)
        thread_process.start()

def get_api_result_from_b():
        result = q.get()
        return result

start_api_call_in_b()
"""
.
.
.
do lots of other stuff
.
.
.
"""
result = get_api_result_from_b()
print(result)
```

This will result in `a.py` making a threaded call to `b.py`'s function and receiving it's result in a global queue. When you want to receive the result, just call the function to fetch received data from queue.

Also keep in mind that any code written outside of functions within `b.py` will be executed immediately on import.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code. Wasn't working so I tried to figure it out and I think the problem is in get_api_result_from_b(). q.get seems a little out of place. I never used this module, so I can be wrong, but I think something should be added to q? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: In the api call in `b.py`, you can see the `global q` declaration, which is basically a way of telling python we will be using the global variable `q`. I have then used `q.put(result)` to put my result into the queue. As long as `q` is not populated, the program will remain blocked at `q.get()`

Comment: As for the issue you're having, is it due to an error, or does the program block itself?

Comment: Ok, my bad, I didn't see the first file things you did with q. I tried running it with these two lines and it didn't work. `NameError: name 'q' is not defined`. How should I define q in file b? The same way it is in file a?

Comment: Have you imported `b.py` into `a.py`? Are you running the API function in `b.py` within a thread in `a.py`, as shown in the solution?

Comment: I think I did. I edited the question so there are both of the files. I removed the server things. Is there anything wrong there? I looked it but couldn't figure anything out. Sorry if I did some stupid thing, I'm a new dev

Comment: Seems like I had neglected some testing. I have updated my solution to include a 'globals.py' file now

Comment: God it worked! for the first time, it could terminate without errors. Thanks, man, you saved me